# Popup magically appeared onscreen moments ago CentOS 7, GNOME?

Tags: discussion

As the title implies I got a pop-up onscreen while visiting [How to install Desktop Environments on CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7) a few minutes ago.

In and of itself it's not concerning. However, the header of the message was "Tehran, Iran" which DOES concern me. I went to screen print the page but accidentally moved the mouse out of focus which, of course, caused the message to lose focus.

I'm still in that page but I cannot recreate the message. Long story short, this is a heads up to stackexchange.

Answer (score 14):

> the header of the message was "Tehran, Iran" which DOES concern me

Ok. Although I fail to see why that in itself should concern you, the most likely explanation is that the question - and answer - stems from esteemed contributor @[αғsнιη](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/72456/%CE%B1%D2%93s%D0%BD%CE%B9%CE%B7) who happens to be located in Tehran, Iran.

You probably clicked, or hovered over this user's icon, and that is why the popup appeared:

[image]

Stay calm.